# How to read the contents of a href with javascript?

Tags: javascript, href, getelementsbyclassname

I have the following html and am stumped as to how to read the contents of the href tag?

```
<p class="xyz-title">
    <a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xyz">
        <span class="field-content">Title here</span>
    </a>
</p>
```

I tried `document.getElementByClass('xyz-title')[0].innerHTML` but that didn't work obviously.

Thanks very much for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a syntax error. It is supposed to be [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName). Use this instead:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('xyz-title')[0].innerHTML
```

And for selecting the `<a>` tag inside the `<p class="xyz-title">` You need to use this code:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('xyz-title')[0].children[0].href
document.getElementsByClassName('xyz-title')[0].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href
```

Or, you can simply use:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/DZhRv/

Comment: That'll return undefined, you're selecting the p rather than the a

Answer (score 0):

`.innerHTML` will give you the content of the element, not the value of any attributes. `.href` will give you the `href` value.

You tried to use `getElementByClass()` by there is no such function - you want `getElementsByClassName()` (as per the tag that you added to the question), a function that returns a list so you do need the `[0]` to get the first one.

To select the anchor element, try:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('xyz-title')[0].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href
```

Or, simpler:

```
document.querySelector('.xyz-title a').href
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6Pg43/

Note that either way will give an error if the elements don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[Working FIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/eLJVe/)**</kbd>

Try this:

```
var href = document.getElementsByClassName('xyz-title')[0].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href;
alert(href);
```